# Change GeoServer admin password via REST

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I have an architecture where I deploy GeoServer instances automatically and I would like to reset the admin password to something random for each instance.  I am running GeoServer 2.16.2 on Debian 10.3. The REST documentation suggests that I can change passwords through a push to the `/rest/security/self/password` path. When I do this, the GeoServer log seems to indicate that the password was changed, yet I can still log in with the default password but can't with the new password.

For example, first I change the password:

```
>>> curl -u admin:geoserver -X PUT http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/self/password -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "content-type: application/json" -d "{  \"newPassword\": \"test\"}"
```

The log indicates the change was successful:

```
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [security.xml] - Successful lock: security/usergroup/default/users.xml.lock
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start storing user/groups for service named default
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [geoserver.security] - Storing user/groups successful for service named default
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [geoserver.security] - Adjusted last modified for file: security/usergroup/default/users.xml
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [geoserver.security] - Adjusted last modified for file: security/usergroup/default/users.xml
29 Apr 20:44:48 INFO [geoserver.rest] - Changed password for user admin
```

But when I do something that requires authentication with the new password, like list the layers:

```
>>> curl -u admin:test -X GET http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers -H  "accept: application/json"
```

I get an error on the server:

```
29 Apr 20:46:27 WARN [geoserver.security] - Failed login, user admin from 172.17.0.1
29 Apr 20:46:27 INFO [geoserver.security] - Brute force attack prevention, delaying login for 1385ms
```

But the original password works fine:

```
>>> curl -u admin:geoserver -X GET http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers -H  "accept: application/json"

{"layers":{"layer":[{"name":"tiger:giant_polygon","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tiger%3Agiant_polygon.json"},{"name":"tiger:poi","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tiger%3Apoi.json"},{"name":"tiger:poly_landmarks","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/rest\/layers\/tiger%3Apoly_landmarks.json"},{"name":"tiger:tiger_roads","href":"http:\/\/localhost:8080\/geoserver\/res...
```

What can I do to change my GeoServer admin password programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you've found a bug, it all works nicely if between setting the new password and testing it via REST you login into the GUI, or [call a reload](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/reload.html) of the config (using the old password) via REST.

So, I would go ahead and file a [bug report](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/issues) with the details of how to generate the issue.

Comment: Looks like a bug for this was created: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9602